# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-4}{(n-1)^2(n+3)^2} $ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-4}{(n-1)^2(n+3)^2} $ converge?

I used the integral test and found that it does, but it was a bit cumbersome. Is there an easier way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know limit comparison test?

Comment: The series is comparable to $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: @Did: Wait, nvm. I see what you're saying.... I can't edit it I will just delete it.

Comment: Didn't think to use limit comparison - seems obvious now. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for a bound. For example
$$0\le\frac{n^2-4}{(n-1)^2(n+3)^2}<\frac{n^2}{(n-1)^2n^2}=\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$$
And it is simple to demonstrate that 
$$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$$
converges, and the sum will be bounded between 
$$0\le\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-4}{(n-1)^2(n+3)^2}\le S$$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use *equivalence*, since it is a series with positive terms:
$$\frac{n^2-4}{(n-1)^2(n+3)^2}\sim_\infty\frac{n^2}{n^2\cdot n^2}=\frac1{n^2}, $$
which converge.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great way to do it, but I'm not sure I'm allowed to use it, since it isn't mentioned in the textbook.

Comment: If I may give my opinion, it should. That's one of the most efficient ways, throwing off all irrelevant details.

Comment: I certainly agree. But I guess the limit comparison test would be the next best thing?

Comment: It is the limit comparison test with $c=1$ (and using some basic results on equivalence, which shorten the proof).

Comment: Good to know! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

By [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition),
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{n\geq 3}\frac{n^2-2n-3}{(n-2)^2 (n+2)^2}&=&\frac{1}{32}\sum_{n\geq 3}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{7}{x-2}-\frac{7}{x+2}}+\color{red}{\frac{10}{(x+2)^2}-\frac{6}{(x-2)^2}}\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{32}\left[\color{blue}{\frac{175}{12}}\color{red}{-6\,\zeta(2)+10\left(\zeta(2)-\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{3^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}\right)}\right]\\&=&\frac{1}{32}\left[\frac{25}{72}+4\,\zeta(2)\right]=\color{purple}{\frac{25}{2304}+\frac{\pi^2}{48}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$
The blue sum is a [telescopic sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html), the red sum is a [well-known sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2?lq=1).